# make: *** [clean] Error 1 and No rule to make target errors

Tags: c, unix, emacs, makefile

I have two c source files, `prog2.c` and `getopts.c`.My `prog2.c` and `getopts.c` files are linked to each other.I made the following makefile from my assignment direction:

```
OPTS= -g -c -Wall -Werror
efile = shell
ofile = prog2.o getopts.o
all: gcc -0 $(efile) <$(ofile)>

shell: \
prog2.o getopts.o
    gcc prog2.o getopts.o -o shell

prog2.o: \
prog2.c
    gcc $(OPTS) prog2.c

getopts.o: \
getopts.c
    gcc $(OPTS) getopts.c

clean:
    rm $(ofile) $(efile)
```

The direction says: for final linking I need to use `gcc -o efile <ofiles>` where efile is the executable file(I believe that will be shell here) and ofiles is the list of all `.o` files. Then I was told to command `make clean` and `make`.For the `make clean` command I get the following error: cannot remove... no file or directory error followed by `make:***[clean] Error 1.` When I do `make` command , I get the following error: make: *** No rule to make target 'gcc', needed by 'all'. Stop. I went through some webpages and similar questions but I'm really not getting it.

Comment: the `gcc -0 $(efile...` should be on the next line, with a tab in front -- as is it's being understood as dependencies for `all` rather than as a command to build it.  Also, that should be `-o` not `-0`

Comment: I did but still getting same error for the make clean command, and for makr, I'm getting some new errors like: syntex error near unexpected token for the make command

Comment: Try `$(ofile)` instead of `<$(ofile)>`, and the `make clean` error is probably because the files you've specified don't exist (though `rm -f` instead of just `rm` should get rid of the error).

Comment: I did what you said,took away <>, but now I'm getting: gcc : prog2.o No such file or directory......The errors are different now.

Comment: rm-f make clean worked! But still make does not work.

Comment: Add dependencies for the targets that should be built before "all", eg. `all: $(ofile)` instead of just `all:`

Comment: Bravo! You are genius!Please put them in the answer section and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the commands to build a target in a make file don't go on the same line as the target name, but on the following lines with a tab in front of each... so the `gcc -0 $(efile) <$(ofile)>` is in the wrong place.

Second, the angle brackets in the directions were probably not meant to actually appear in your command.

Also, if a target requires other targets to be built first, those targets should be listed as dependencies after the target name, separated from it by a colon.

And, the option to specify the output file for gcc is `-o` rather than `-0`.

So your `all` target becomes:

```
all: $(ofile)
    gcc -o $(efile) $(ofile)
```

The error when running `make clean` occurred because the files it tried to delete didn't exist, as a successful build hadn't been done.  Adding the "force" option for `rm` causes it to "ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt", so that the command succeeds even when the files are missing and `make` doesn't complain.  So that becomes:

```
clean:
    rm -f $(ofile) $(efile)
```

Note though that usually individual programs and libraries built with the makefile each have their own targets, and "all" usually just depends on each of them so that all of them get built... so using the "all" target as you have is a bit unusual.